# is it possible to use Generic dynamic in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
protocol Base {
    associatedtype M
    var data:M { get set }
    func update(data:M)
}

class ViewA : Base {
    var data: String = ""
    func update(data: String) {}
}

class ViewB : Base {
    var data: Int = 2
    func update(data: Int) {}
}

var dataArr : [Any] = ["1",2]
var viewArr : [Any] = [ViewA(), ViewB()]

func updatData() {
    
    func update<C, T>(view:C, data:T) where C : Base, C.M == T {
        view.update(data: data)
    }
    
    for i in 0..<2 {
        let view = viewArr[i]
        let data = dataArr[I]
// ! there is a errr here, Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Base'
        update(view: view, data: data)
    }
}
```

My Views conform to this 'Base' protocol which define what type of data my view use

And I want to implement this  updatData function dynamic tell if data can be send to view (base on viwe.m type is same to data's type)
But it is seems to be impossible in Swift?

Comment: It’s always going to problematic to us Any as a collection element type so this isn’t really about generics

Answer (score 1):

Array of `Any` object pass as `Base` Protocol create conflict.
so add one more class for Base class of `ViewA` and `ViewB`

```
protocol Base {
  associatedtype M
  var data: M { get set }
  func update(data: M)
}

class Base1: Base {
  typealias M = Any
  var data: Any = ""
  func update(data: Any) {
      print("Udate \(data)")
  }
}

class ViewA: Base1 {
  //typealias M = String
  //var data: String = ""
  override func update(data: Any) {
      print("test")
  }
}

class ViewB: Base1 {
  //typealias M = Int
  //var data: Int = 2
  override func update(data: Any) {
      print(data)
      print("Udate")
  }
}

var dataArr: [Any] = ["1", 2]
var viewArr: [Any] = [ViewA(), ViewB()]

func updatData() {

  func update<C, T>(view: C, data: T) where C: Base, C.M == T {
    view.update(data: data)
  }

  for i in 0..<2 {
    let view = viewArr[i]
    let data = dataArr[i]
    update(view: view as! Base1, data: data)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: in this way， View can't  get the model of the type it wanted, View has to convert it to M type .  `class ViewA2: Base1 {
  override func update(data: Any) {
      //  I don't want this option binding code here, that's why I have 'Base' protocol for the first place
      if let myModel = data as? Int {
          // do something
      } else {
          // I have to put assert here to tell the caller he passed the wrong type 
      }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a type erased `Base` concrete type here: `AnyBase`:

```
public final class AnyBase: Base {
    fileprivate let _boxed: _Box<M>
    
    public init<Concrete: Base>(_ concrete: Concrete) where Concrete.M == M {
        self._boxed = _ConcreteBox(concrete)
    }
    
    // Base conformance
    public var data: M { _boxed.data }
    public func update(data: M) {
        _boxed.update(data: data)
    }
    
    // Type erasure
    fileprivate class _Box<T>: Base {
        init() {
            guard type(of: self) != _Box.self else { fatalError("Can't create _Box instances, create a sub class instance instead ") }
        }

        // Base conformance
        var base: M {
             get { fatalError("Must override") }
             set { fatalError("Must override") }
        }
        func update(data: M) {
              fatalError("Must override")
        }
    }

    fileprivate final class _ConcreteBox<Concrete: Base>: _Box<Concrete.M> where M == Concrete.M {
        let _concrete: Concrete
    
        init(_ concrete: Concrete) {
            self._concrete = concrete
            super.init()
        }

        // Base conformance
        override var data: {
            get { _concrete.data }
            set { _concrete.data = newValue  }
        }
        
        override func update(data: M) {
             _concrete.update(data: data)
        }
    }

 }
```

Now you can store different concrete instances of `Base<M>` in an array by adopting the type erased `AnyBase<M>` instead of using `Any` in your arrays.